# xml won't validate, having trouble with namespaces

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm about to pull my hair out trying to figure out why this won't validate. I keep getting the error

> cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ret'. [13]

Before I was getting the error on schemaLocation and it was telling me the URIs needed to be the same length or something but I fixed that by making schemaLocation, target, and targetNamespace the same.

But it still can't find my "ret" element declaration and I can't find out why. Now I'm not very good at namespaces, I don't understand them as well as everything else.

Any help would be much appreciated to figure out how to fix this error.

Oh also my .xsd file is named "ret" and so is my first element. I don't think that's causing an issue but so it doesn't confuse anyone. It's just a requirement I have.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="urn:My.Namespace"
xmlns:target="urn:My.Namespace ret.xsd"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
>

    <xs:element name="ret">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="feed" />
                <xs:element ref="doc-copyright" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute fixed="1.0" name="version" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="date" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

This is part of my .xsd file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ret 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:My.Namespace ret.xsd">
</ret>
```

This is the part of the xml file that won't validate. If I need to post more I can. It is pretty long though. I'm wondering if this error is because My.Namespace isn't a valid namespace? I just don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your schema, you said that your elements will be bound to the `urn:My.Namespace` when you have `@targetNamespace="urn:My.Namespace"`.

But your instance XML document has a "ret" element that is bound to the `http://www.w3schools.com` namespace.

In order for it to be schema valid, it must be bound to the `urn:Ny.Namespace` namespace.

Change it to:

```
<ret 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:My.Namespace"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:My.Namespace ret.xsd">
</ret>
```

and then deal with the other validation issues (no feed, doc-copyright, @version, or @date)